# ios Symbolication Server side

Tags: objective-c

How to symbolicate the ios crash report after uploading to server in a linux environment where iOS development tools and scripts will not be available. I know Apple uses atos and some other tools  to map the hex addresses to symbol along with .dYSM file.

I can upload .dYSM file along with crash report to server. Refered QuincyKit, but they are doing symbolication locally. But other's like HockeyApp and Critterism are doing it remotely.

Pls recommend the possible ways to do it in server.

Comment: Are you certain that HockeyApp and Critterism aren't running OSX Server rather than Linux?

Comment: Even though if they are using OX Server, it will be difficult to afford that infrastructure for a simple application. Better thinking of put some effort on software rather than in the hardware.

Comment: OK conversation over then I guess.  I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement your own linux compatible versions of `atos`, `otool` and `dwarfdump` (at least the functionality needed for symbolication). The Apple tools are not open source and only run on Mac OS X.

None of the services provide a solution that can be used by 3rd parties on non OS X systems. So your only chance, besides implementing the required functionality to run on your linux system, is to do it on a Mac like QuincyKit does it, see https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit/wiki/Remote-symbolication or use a third party service.

Note: I am the creator of QuincyKit and Co-Founder of HockeyApp.

Comment: Will implement own versions of mentioned tools- Thanks

Answer (score 9):

It is possible. You can take a look at https://github.com/facebook/atosl

I got it working under Linux. (Ubuntu Server) However, it takes some time to get it up and running.

---

### Installing `atosl`

First, you need to install `libdwarf-dev`, `dwarfdump`, `binutils-dev` and `libiberty-dev`.

E.g. on Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdwarf-dev dwarfdump binutils-dev libiberty-dev
```

Download or clone the atosl repo from GitHub:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/atosl.git
```

CD to the atosl dir

```
$ cd atosl
```

Create a local config `config.mk.local` which contains a flag with the location of your binutil apps. (in Ubuntu by default that's `/usr/bin`). If you're not sure, you can find out by executing `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/binutils.list | less` and copy the path of the file `objdump`. E.g. if the entry is `/usr/bin/objdump`, your path is `/usr/bin`.

So in the end, your `config.mk.local` should look like this:

```
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/bin
```

Compile it:

```
$ make
```

Now you can start using it:

```
$ ./atosl --help
```

---

### Symbolicating example

To show how `atosl` is used, I'll provide a simple example.

Now let's take a look at a line from the crash log:

```
13  ErrorApp    0x000ea294 0xe3000 + 29332
```

To symbolicate this, we will need the `load address`, and the `runtime address`.

In this example the `runtime address` is `0x000ea294`, and the `load address` is `0xe3000`.

Now we have everything we need:

```
$ ./atosl -o [YOUR_dSYM_FILE] -l [LOAD_ADDRESS] [RUNTIME_ADDRESS]
```

In this example:

```
$ ./atosl -o ErrorApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/ErrorApp -l 0xe3000 0x000ea294
```

Which returns the symbolicated line:

```
main (in ErrorApp) (main.m:16)
```

---

### FYI

Your `vmaddr`, which usually is `0x00001000`, you can find by looking at the segname `__TEXT` Mach-O load command of your binary. In my example, this happens to be different, namely `0x00004000`

To find the `address`, we need to do some math.

The `address` is found by the following formula:

```
address = vmaddr + ( runtime_address - load_address )
```

In this example our address is:

```
0x00004000 + ( 0x000ea294 - 0xe3000 ) = 0xB294
```

---

I haven't played around with this that much yet, but for now it seems to give me the results I needed. Maybe it will work for you too.

Comment: Can this solution be used in APM service like HockeyApp?